# Stretching one table row to the size of another

Tags: android, layout, dialog

I'm developing a yatzy game and the player get to choose where to put its score from a dialog. However I'm having a bit of trouble with making the layout doing what I want it to. I've splitted up the regular score card to avoid scrolling on smaller screens and placed the two parts in separate table layouts.

These two table layouts contain a different amount of rows and have different heights. Can anyone tell me how to stretch the right table layouts rows in order to give them the same height?

Here's a pic:

[image: I'm going to shuffle up the row contents a bit too.]

And here's the layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayoutHolder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:baselineAligned="false" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayoutLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_row_padding" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/dice_border_gray"
                    android:src="@drawable/d1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv0"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_row_padding" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/dice_border_gray"
                    android:src="@drawable/d2" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_row_padding" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/dice_border_gray"
                    android:src="@drawable/d3" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_row_padding" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/dice_border_gray"
                    android:src="@drawable/d4" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_row_padding" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/dice_border_gray"
                    android:src="@drawable/d5" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_row_padding" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/dice_border_gray"
                    android:src="@drawable/d6" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_row_padding" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvScUpperSum"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/tv_black_right_border"
                    android:text="@string/sum" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_row_padding" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvScBonus"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/tv_black_right_border"
                    android:text="@string/bonus" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayoutRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_row_padding" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvSc1Pair"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/tv_black_right_border"
                    android:text="@string/OnePair" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:duplicateParentState="true"
                    android:text="" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_row_padding" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvSc2Pairs"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/tv_black_right_border"
                    android:text="@string/TwoPairs" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_row_padding" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvSc3ofaKind"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/tv_black_right_border"
                    android:text="@string/ThreeOfAKind" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv10"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_row_padding" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvSc4ofaKind"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/tv_black_right_border"
                    android:text="@string/FourOfAKind" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv11"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_row_padding" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvFullHouse"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/tv_black_right_border"
                    android:text="@string/fullHouse" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv12"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_row_padding" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvScSmallStr"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/tv_black_right_border"
                    android:text="@string/smallStr" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv13"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_row_padding" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvScLargeStr"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/tv_black_right_border"
                    android:text="@string/largeStr" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv14"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow15"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_row_padding" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvScChance"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/tv_black_right_border"
                    android:text="@string/chance" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv15"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow16"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_row_padding" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvScYatzy"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/tv_black_right_border"
                    android:text="@string/yatzy" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv16"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow17"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_row_padding" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvScSum"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/tv_black_right_border"
                    android:text="@string/sum" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv17"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by giving the right table layout the height "match_parent" and then adding weights on the table rows in it.